# Validation of form using jquery mobile or javascript

Tags: javascript

I  am using the following code which displays a form. The form elements should be validated . Please find the attached code with what i have tried.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <body>
     <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>site Details</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

    <a href="#Site entry1" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Enter the details of site</a>

    <a href="#Modify site" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Modify site details</a>

    </div>

     </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="Site entry1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <h1>Welcome To enter the details of site</h1>
        </div>


    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
        <form id= "1">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="sitename">Site name:</label>
                <input type="text" sitename="name" id="sitename" value=""  />
            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="siteno">Site name:</label>
                <input type="text" siteno="siteno" id="siteno" value=""  />
            </li>

            <a href="#Site entry2" data-role="button" onclick="validate()" data-inline="true">Next</a>

        </ul>

        </form>
        </div>


    </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="Site entry2">

        <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#Site entry1"  data-role="button" data-icon="back">previous</a>
        <h1>Welcome To enter the module details of site</h1>
        </div>


        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="content-primary">
            <form>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="moduleno">name:</label>
                    <input type="text" modulename="moduleno" id="moduleno" value=""  />
                </li>
                <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                        </fieldset>
                </li>

            </ul>

            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        <a href="#Site entry3" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="Site entry3">

        <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#Site entry2" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="back">previous</a>
       <h1>Welcome To enter the exe details of site</h1>
        </div>


        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="content-primary">
            <form>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="modulename">name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
                </li>

                <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                        </fieldset>
                </li>

            </ul>

            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        <a href="#home"  data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="Modify site">

        <div data-role="header">
        <a href="home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <h1>List of sites </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

find the following scripting

```
function validate()         
        {
        var siteName = document.getElementById("siteName").value;

        var siteNo = document.getElementById("siteNo").value;

        if (siteName.length == 0)           
        {
         alert("Please, enter your name");
         return false;
        }
            if (siteNo.length == 0)
            {
        alert("Please, enter your no");
        return false;
            var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
              if(siteNo.value.match(numbers))  
              {  
               return true;  
              }  
     }
}
```

How to validate that site no will be only numbers and site name only text.
The code i have tried above is not serving for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your html has an error too .. there two body tags .. remove one

```
<body>
    <body>
```

Alse check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cDB9/1/) for validation. Make use of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Statements after a `return` usually are not executed. Change:

```
function validate()         
{
        var siteName = document.getElementById("siteName").value;

        var siteNo = document.getElementById("siteNo").value;

        if (siteName.length == 0)           
        {
             alert("Please, enter your name");
             return false;
        }

        if (siteNo.length == 0)
        {
             alert("Please, enter your no");
             return false;
        } // !!

        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(siteNo.value.match(numbers))  
        {  
             return true;  
        }
        else
             return false;            // !!!
}
```

Recommendation: if the code would have been properly indented, this error would have been quite more obvious.